# Ubuntu desktop always freeze after no interaction for sometime

Tags: ubuntu, desktop-environment, xubuntu

I install Xubuntu desktop environment on "Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS" server;

It works fine after successfully login, but if leave it for some time without any interaction, the desktop will completely freeze and only mouse moves. TTY and SSH are still able to work and it recovers after restart lightdm service.

**Could anyone help provide some suggestions about how to debug or get log message when the issue happens?**

And of course, it will be great if there is any method to fix the problem directly.

Thanks a lot in advance.

*BTW, I have tried to replace Ubuntu default desktop, but it is even not able to login, so I think that maybe another topic.*

Comment: I thought Xubuntu was 20.4 LTS an OS were one installs the Xubuntu desktop on the Xubuntu OS. Try uninstalling the Xubuntu desktop and see if your Ubuntu desktop works.

Comment: Thanks for reply. In fact it works fine with gnome desktop environment before, but it suddenly doesn't work a few days ago (Desktop is blank only mouse works). So I try different desktop environemnt to fix it, finally find Xubuntu can work, but still have this issue as current topic described.